Relaxation Time vs. Mixing Time
Dear StackExchange community
I am reading through Levin's and Peres' "Markov Chains and Mixing Times" as well as "The mixing time evolution of Glauber dynamics for the mean-field Ising model" by Ding, Lubetzky and Peres. Throughout the works, the mixing time of a Markov chain $(X_t)$ with kernel $P$, given by
$$
t_{\operatorname{mix}} := t_{\text{mix}}(1/4) = \min\{ t \geq 0 : d(t) \leq 1/4\}
$$
is treated and analyzed, where $d(t) := \max\{\|P^t(x,\cdot) - \mu\|_{TV} : x \in \Omega \}$ denotes "distance from stationarity" and $\mu$ is the chain's stationary measure, and put into perspective with the relaxation time, i.e. its inverse spectral gap $$t_{\text{rel}} := \mathtt{gap}^{-1}.$$ Multiple times, it is stated that $t_{\text{rel}} \leq t_{\text{mix}}$ always holds for the chain's magnetization chain $(S_t)$ with $S_t = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{v \in V} X_t(v)$ is an obvious fact, but I don't see how this is obvious.
Thanks for any clarification that may help form my intuition. Have a great day.
